# Relationship between in-sample and out-sample periods length

Tags: backtesting, forecasting, estimation

I have two general questions regarding "in-sample fitting vs. out-of-sample backtesting" kind of analyses. Is there any relationship between the length of the data collected for in-sample fitting ($a$) and the length of the data reserved for out-of-sample performance ($b$)?

Should $a$ be longer than $b$? If yes by how much (in absolute or relative terms)? Or is it okay to have a longer $b$ than $a$? Is the 50:50 rule discussed in the following link justified? Is it used in academia or by practicioners? [What is the ideal ratio of in-sample length to out-of-sample length?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/what-is-the-ideal-ratio-of-in-sample-length-to-out-of-sample-length)

Let's now assume you somehow determined that $b$ is too long for $a$. Would you extend $a$ and reduce $b$ keeping $a+b$ unchanged? Or just reduce $b$, and thus reducing the length of the testing period?